# asp.net: why am I getting System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System. String] when I try to print values from a list in an asp.net grid view?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net

I'm trying to create a session where I store the values of a certain column. So I created this list to display the value if selected but I'm getting this in the other page System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System. String] instead of the actual values.

This is the first page's code:

```
Private Sub BindGrid()
 Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbconnection").ConnectionString)
 con.Open()
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select distinct Name,assignment_id, Description ,cod from assignments 
     INNER Join crmsLecturerXCrsSection ON crmsLecturerXCrsSection.emp_key = assignments.emp_key
     INNER Join CRMSStudentsXCrsSection ON CRMSStudentsXCrsSection.CrsSec_id = crmsLecturerXCrsSection.CrsSec_id
     INNER JOIN CRMS_CourseXSection ON CRMS_CourseXSection.CrsSec_id = CRMSStudentsXCrsSection.CrsSec_id
     INNER JOIN CRMSECTIONS ON CRMSECTIONS.SEC_ID = CRMS_CourseXSection.SEC_ID
     left JOIN crmscourses ON crmscourses.crs_id = CRMS_CourseXSection.crs_id
     INNER JOIN CRMS_CourseXSection cs ON CRMS_CourseXSection.SEC_ID = CRMSECTIONS.SEC_ID
     INNER JOIN CRMSSEMESTER ON CRMSSEMESTER.SEM_ID = CRMS_CourseXSection.SEM_ID
     where  CRMSSEMESTER.SEM_ID='1'   
     and crmsLecturerXCrsSection.emp_key='436' and crmscourses.crs_desc='" + Session("crs") + "'", con)
 Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
 Dim dt As New DataTable()
 da.Fill(dt)
 Dim listIDs As New List(Of String)
 Dim row As DataRow
 For Each row In dt.Rows
     listIDs.Add(row("assignment_id"))
 Next
 Session("assid") = listIDs
 cmd.Connection = con
 GridView1.DataSource = cmd.ExecuteReader()
 GridView1.DataBind()
 End Sub
```

This is the second page:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
Label1.Text = Session("assid").ToString()
   Dim con1 As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("dbconnection").ConnectionString)
 Dim cmd1 As New SqlCommand("select * from assignments where assignment_id ='" + String.Join(",", Session("assid")) + "'", con1)


End Sub
```

Comment: You've put a list into this object: Session("assid") = listIDs

Comment: In this case `Session("assid").ToString()` is equivalent to `(New List(Of String)).ToString()` which will output `System.Collections.Generic.List\`1[System.String]`

Comment: You have a bunch of side issues with your code: don't inject data into your query, it's **dangerous** and can cause injection attacks and syntax errors. Use parameters instead. You must dispose your connection, command, adapter and reader with `Using`. Consider using table aliases such as `crmsLecturerXCrsSection  AS sec`. Specify which table the columns are coming from, such as `select distinct sec.Name`. Do you really need `distinct`? it is a very expensive operator, rethink your joins, maybe one of them is causing duplicates. .....

Comment: .... Select only the columns you need, you appear to be using only one. If you are outputting to a `List` then you don't need an adapter or a datatable, just loop a reader `Using reader = cmd.ExecuteReader() While reader.Read() listIDs.Add(DirectCast(reader["assignment_id"], String))`

Comment: @Charlieface thank you so much for your suggestions and advice . I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put a `List(Of String)` into `Session("assid")` so that's what you get out. If you call `ToString` on that, you'll get the type name, which is exactly what you're seeing, i.e. `"System.Collections.Generic.List'1[System.String]"`. Just as always, if you want to see the items in the list then you'll need to get the items out first. Exactly how you do that depends on exactly what you want to do with those items. If, for instance, you just wanted to show the items in a comma-delimited list, you could do this:

```vb
Dim ids = DirectCast(Session("assid"), List(Of String))

Label1.Text = String.Join(", ", ids)
```

Comment: thank you so much. I tired it and it worked.

Comment: @HansKeﬆing sadly I don't have the privilege to accept answers yet.

Comment: As far as I know, you are always allowed to accept an answer to your own question. There is a [15 minute timeout window](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50697/time-limit-on-accepting-an-answer)

Comment: @HansKeﬆing I did accept it.